# Что такое Hex? Это шифровка?

Tags: java, android

Есть проект и есть там методы:

- Конвертировать в `hex`
- Конвертировать из `hex`

Вопрос: что такое `hex`?

Comment: шестнадцатеричная система счисления

Comment: Широко используется программистами

Comment: Скорее всего имеется в виду конвертация из _строкового_ представления.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример кода, где используются эти функции, а также сигнатуры самих функций.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hex - это обозначение 16-ричной системы счисления!
Bin - двоичной системы счисления!
Oct - восьмеричная!
Dec- это наша десятичная система счисления!